# Vagrant taking up too much space

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I switch between four projects on my local machine and I use vagrant for each on of them.

```
$ vagrant global-status
id       name    provider   state    directory
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
3e1f21e  default virtualbox running  d:/www/project1/source
9080cd0  default virtualbox poweroff d:/www/project2/source
c4e0461  default virtualbox poweroff d:/www/project3/source
b75805d  default virtualbox running  d:/www/project4/source
```

However, my C drive (I'm on a windows 7 machine) is showing that I'm using `16.4GB` on the `\User\VirtualBox VMs`

It seems a little excessive for just 4 VMs. So I opened VirtualBox and saw that I had 7 VMs on there.

I'm thinking these are boxes that I previously destroyed but I could very well be wrong.

I couldn't find anything about it on the web. But could I just delete these items or are they important to vagrant? If so, how can I set up vagrant without having to use up too much space on my laptop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you destroyed the boxes with `vagrant destroy` and it finished without errors, the box should be gone from Virtualbox as well. If this didn't happen, you can remove the box manually from Virtualbox. Just make sure to also delete the local files (Virtualbox will ask you if you wanna keep the HD, which you don't)!

If you are unsure which boxes to remove from Virtualbox because they are all named he same, you can either destroy all boxes from vagrant and then remove all boxes left to Virtualbox. Or you can start all vagrant boxes using `vagrant up` and then delete the ones from Virtualbox which don't run.

Comment: I can't really destroy the boxes since there is data on some DBs that I don't have backups of (A problem that I'm also trying to work into my vagrant workflow). But that tip on running all boxes to and delete the ones that don't run seem to be right on track.

Comment: Although on second thought, I had done some (read: very little) research between the time I asked this question and your answer and seem to remember finding out that these extra VMs on Vbox are the boxes that you add to Vagrant (so it's precise32, centOs and some other). Is this about right or am I way off?

Comment: No, the boxes you add to vagrant are downloaded but not showing up in Virtualbox because they are only the .box file plus some Metadata, not  a real Virtualbox machine you can boot.